# Why do I get the same result with rand() every time I compile and run?

Tags: c, random

Whenever I run this code, I get a same result.

Program

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int agrc, const char *argv[]) {
 int i = rand();
 printf("%d\n",i);
 for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
  printf("%d\n",rand());
 }
}
```

Result:

```
41
18467
6334
26500
19169
15724
11478
29358
26962
24464
5705
```

I ran this on `mingw`. Actually I am learning `Objective-C`

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694827/random-float-number-help

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to seed the rand function with a unique number before it can be used. The easiest method is to use [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time)

For example

```
srand(time(NULL));
rand();//now returns a random number
```

The reason is that the random numbers provided by rand() (or any other algorithm based function) aren't random. The rand function just takes its current numerical state, applies a transformation, saves the result of the transformation as the new state and returns the new state.

So to get rand to return different pseudo random numbers, you first have to set the state of rand() to something unique.

Comment: To add to this answer: Each seed number (time() in this case) will create a different list of random numbers.  But, if the seed # is the same, the list will be the same.

Comment: The function `time` takes a pointer to a `time_t` object. Do `srand(time(NULL));` instead. And be aware that several calls to `time(NULL)` within the same second all return the same value.

Comment: also really important to mention it's not secure, and should never be used to generate passwords, keys, etc.

Answer (score 11):

You want to initialize the PRNG.

Initialize it **once** (typically inside `main()`) with a call to the `srand()` function.

If you do not initialize the PRNG, the default is to have it initialized with the value `1`. Of course initializing it with some other constant value will not give you different pseudo random numbers for different runs of the program.

```
srand(1); /* same as default */
srand(42); /* no gain, compared to the line above */
```

You need to initialize with a value that changes with each run of the program. The value returned from the `time()` function is the value most often used.

```
srand(time(NULL)); /* different pseudo random numbers almost every run */
```

The problem with `time(NULL)` is that it returns the same value at the same second. So, if you call your program twice at 11:35:17 of the same day you will get the same pseudo random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to Yacoby's answer - I was slightly surprised that it didn't default to a time-based seed, so I looked up the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand):

> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.

So if you change your code to use `seed(1)` you should still see the same output - but `seed(time())` will make it change each time.

Comment: It defaults to a fixed seed so that you can, if necessary, get reproducible results from your program(s) (e.g. during testing, debugging, yaddah, yaddah).

Answer (score 3):

The output from **rand** is *pseudo*-random, which means that it looks effectively random, but is computed the same way each time, starting from a special value called the seed. With the same seed value, you get the same sequence of random numbers.

To set a different seed, use the standard C function **void srand(unsigned int)** once in your code before you start generating random numbers. One common way of getting a different sequence of random numbers each time you run the program is to base the seed on the clock time. E.g. **srand(clock())**