# Two random arrays

Tags: c, arrays, random, srand

I want to fill 2 arrays with random numbers,  i have to use srand(time(NULL)), but when i do the arrays have the same numbers.I created the second array through a function so the time will be different but again the arrays have the same numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int stand(int *arr1,int n)
{
 int i,*arr2;
 arr2=array1(n);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("A= %d\n",*(arr1+i));

 printf("\n");

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("b= %d\n",*(arr2+i));

}

int array1(int n)
{
 int i,*pinx;

 pinx = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    *(pinx+i)=rand()%21+30;
 return pinx;

}

int main()
{
  int *arr1,n,i;

  printf("Give size: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  arr1=(int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    *(arr1+i)=rand()%21+30;

  stand(arr1,n);

  return 0;

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get the same result with rand() every time I compile and run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783629/why-do-i-get-the-same-result-with-rand-every-time-i-compile-and-run)

Comment: seed only once is enough

Comment: i don't think so, Joachim Isaksson gave me the answer that i was looking for, straight forward answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: how's that different from my comment above? I said srand should be called only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time(NULL)` returns the time in seconds. If both calls to `srand(time(NULL));` run within the same second, `srand` gets the same value both times and initializes the random number generator to generate the same sequence of random numbers.

Just call `srand` *once* at the start of the program and remove the other use and things should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably set the same seed `time(NULL)` for both calls assuming both of them gets called within the same second of time. You should set a different seed, if you want to get a different set of random numbers.