# Basic C rand in range outputting the same number

Tags: c

I am trying to find random numbers from 1 to 5. I made this code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int r;

  r = rand() % 5 + 1;
  printf("%d ", r);
    
  
  switch (r){
    case 1:
      printf("1\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("2\n");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("3\n");
      break;
    case 4:
      printf("4\n");
      break;
    case 5:
      printf("5\n");
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, for both outputs, for the first print, and the switch, I just get the output "4 4." How do I get it so that each time it's a different number in that list? Do I need to loop it?

Comment: Why would you expect the outputs to be different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get the same result with rand() every time I compile and run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783629/why-do-i-get-the-same-result-with-rand-every-time-i-compile-and-run)

Comment: If you want multiple random numbers, you need to call `rand` multiple times.

Comment: You have to seed the random number generator by calling `srand()` with a suitable value.  Ideally, the seed should itself be random.  Be careful and [only call `srand()` once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/15168), though.