# c - random number generator

Tags: c, random

How do I generate a random number between 0 and 1?

Comment: Truly random or pseudorandom?

Comment: @tm1 -- Pseudorandom numbers only approximate the properties of random numbers and won't necessarily be suitable for applications that require real randomness, like cryptography.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator for an explanation.

Comment: Another article that may be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random

Comment: `function getRandom() { return 0.4; } // chosen by fair dice roll. guaranteed to be random.`

Comment: @KennyTM You have dice with sides that can sum to every real number between 0 and 1? Impressive.

Comment: My fair die has 6 sides, all has 0.4 written on it.

Comment: @Tyler: I'm pretty confident that the questioner does not need the output to be capable of outputting *any* real number between 0 and 1. At least not if the program is supposed to terminate. pi/4? e/3?

Comment: duplicate many times over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190870/i-need-to-generate-random-numbers-in-c-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167253/implementation-of-rand and others. BTW, @tm1, I found that with this search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+random+number .

Comment: @dmckee: It seems the ones that you quote here all generate random integers. Your search does include http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694827/random-float-number-help , which is more relevant.

Comment: @N1.1 Strictly speaking it shouldn't matter :)

Answer (score 22):

You can generate a pseudorandom number using [stdlib.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdlib.h).  Simply include stdlib, then call

```
double random_number = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
```

Comment: For reference, this will give values in [0.0, 1.0] i.e. including both 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: And most importantly, it will most likely not be fair (!) There are many implementations where the set [0.0, 1.0] contains more than RAND_MAX elements. (_In C, the set [0.0, 1.0] is a countable finite set_)

Comment: @MSalters, that's an interesting problem, any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: it really depends on the application. The first thing to realize is that the set `[0.00, 0.01]` contains many more elements than the set `[0.99, 1.00]`. This is because `1E-100 > 0` but `1 - 1E-100 == 1`. For many applications this can be counteracted by setting `p(x) = 1.0/(_nextafter(x)-x);` although this technically works for the range `[0.0, 1.0)`. The result is that p(x) depends on x, but `SUM[0<=i<x](p(i)) == x`

Comment: Oh, and often it just doesn't matter - many applications would work even with `double arr[11] = {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 }; return arr[rand % 11];`

Answer (score 9):

Assuming OP wants either 0 or 1:

```
srand(time(NULL));
foo = rand() & 1;
```

Edit inspired by comment:
Old `rand()` implementations had a flaw - lower-order bits had much shorter periods than higher-order bits so use of low-order bit for such implementations isn't good.
If you know your `rand()` implementation suffers from this flaw, use high-order bit, like this:

```
foo = rand() >> (sizeof(int)*8-1)
```

assuming regular 8-bits-per-byte architectures

Comment: you should shift the result of `rand()` to account for problems with linear congruential generators

Comment: @Christoph Thank you, I've edited my post to reflect your point.

Comment: Who said `rand()` uses all 32 bits? `RAND_MAX` on MSVC is 0x7fff, for instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: you don't have to assume 8-bits-per-byte if you use `rand() >> (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1)`.

Comment: use an arbitrary shift `(rand() >> RAND_SHIFT) & 1` and check at compile-time that `RAND_MAX > (1 << RAND_SHIFT)`; alternatively, if `RAND_MAX` is of form `2^n - 1`, you can use `rand() / ((RAND_MAX + 1) >> 1)` to get the most significant bit; you can again check this at compile-time via `(RAND_MAX & (RAND_MAX + 1)) == 0`

Comment: You can always use `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)` to get a single random bit, independent of the exact value of `RAND_MAX`. This could be slightly unfair if RAND_MAX is even, though. Easiest to see if you assume RAND_MAX is 2: `rand()` would generate either 0, 1 or 2. It's impossible to extract a single unbiased random bit from that.

Comment: @MSalters: Won't you always get 0 with `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)`?

Answer (score 8):

[man 3 drand48](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/drand48.html) is *exactly* what you asked for.

> The *drand48()* and *erand48()* functions return non-negative, double-precision, floating-point values, uniformly distributed over the interval [0.0 , 1.0].

These are found in `#include <stdlib.h>` on UNIX platforms.  They're not in ANSI C, though, so (for example) you won't find them on Windows unless you bring your own implementation (e.g. [LibGW32C](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm)).